# Are the jOOQ fluent API intermediate results immutable?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

If I save an intermediate result from the fluent API query builder, will later calls modify it? (In other words, are the intermediate results immutable?) For example,

```java
final var a = create.select().from(AUTHOR);
final var before1920 = a.where(AUTHOR.YEAR_OF_BIRTH.gt(1920).fetch();
final var authorSql = a.where(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME.eq("Paulo")).getSql();
```

Can I be confident that `a` was not modified by the later statements?

If this is not the case, my main desire is to sometimes log the SQL from queries either to audit logs or debugging logs. Can I safely call `getSQL()` before or after calling `fetch*()` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Mutability of the jOOQ DSL

As of jOOQ 3.16, yes, those particular methods expose mutable behaviour, so you can dynamically construct the query as you did. See also the [jOOQ manual's section about mutability](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-api/mutability-historic/), which hints at this possibly changing in the (far) future, in favour of more predictable immutable DSL APIs.

But even if this can be exploited, you should not construct [dynamic SQL queries](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/) like this. Use the recommended approach:

```java
Condition condition = AUTHOR.YEAR_OF_BIRTH.gt(1920);

if (...)
    condition = condition.and(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME.eq("Paulo"));

create.select()
      .from(AUTHOR)
      .where(condition)
      .fetch();
```

This doesn't help you with your *actual* question, but it answers parts of the question you have asked, namely, you shouldn't rely on this mutable behaviour.

#### Specific questions

> Can I be confident that a was not modified by the later statements?

No, you cannot. `a` was modified, see [the section about mutability](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-api/mutability-historic/).

> my main desire is to sometimes log the SQL from queries either to audit logs or debugging logs

You can either [use the built in execute logging](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-execute-logging/), which logs all queries to the `DEBUG` level.

> Can I safely call `getSQL()` before or after calling `fetch*()` methods?

Yes, those calls are safe. That's what the above execute logging does, too, in order to apply formatting, inlining of bind values for logging purposes, etc.